# How can I count methods call and correspond start to end number?

Tags: java

I have a following codes, is there a nice way to count number in State enum ??

I want to move StateHolders's function to State enum, but I don't know how to correspond start number to end number.

```
public enum State{
   START("start"),
   END("end");

   public String msg;

   private State(String msg){
      this.msg = msg;
   }       
}

public class StateHolder{

   private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
   private int current;

   public String start(){
      current = counter.getAndIncrement();
      return State.START.msg + " " + current;
   }

   public String end(){
      return State.END.msg + " " + current;
   }
} 


public static void main(String[] args){

    StateHolder sh1 = new StateHolder();
    StateHolder sh2 = new StateHolder();

    System.out.println(sh1.start); // start 0
    System.out.println(sh2.start); // start 1
    System.out.println(sh1.end); // end 0
    System.out.println(sh2.end); // end 1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
public enum State {
...

    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public AtomicInteger counter() {
        return counter;
    }
...
```

}

```
public class StateHolder {

    private int current;

    public String start() {
        current = State.START.counter().getAndIncrement();
        return State.START.msg + " " + current;
    }
...
}
```